# parsing XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have an XML that I would like to parse then send the result into a txt file.

The XML file is build from blocks like this one :

```
<rpc-reply message-id="12"
xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
<user-stats>
<allocated-user-count>10</allocated-user-count>
<current-user-count>3</current-user-count>
<max-active-user-count-24hrs>2</max-active-usercount-
24hrs>
<min-active-user-count-24hrs>0</min-active-usercount-
24hrs>
</user-stats>
</rpc-reply>
```

All the blocks will start with  and and with

I would like to remove all the tags and get the results by line and copy them in a text file. For example :

```
allocated user count <tab> current-user-count <tab> max-user-count
    100 <tab> 1<tab> 2<tab>
    100 <tab> 0<tab> 2<tab> (info taken from the second RPC block)
```

etc

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [xmltodict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmltodict) module for this.

You will need to install it using

```
pip install xmltodict
```

Once you've it, just do

```
import xmltodict
data = xmltodict.parse(xmldata)
```

This will give you an early traversable python dict, which you can then use to get the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways you can do this.

The most accessible would be to use the [XML Processing Modules](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.html), included in Python's standard library, to read the XML, and then [use a text file object](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) to output to the text file after doing your processing.